# Xampp not displaying PHP pages in htdocs due to "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, localhost, xampp

I installed xampp this evening and none of my PHP pages will display.
I am storing all my pages in the htdocs folder as directed too and calling via `http://localhost/index.php` and nothing appears? All systems are online. Is there anything else that should have been done before copying over my pages?

i'm using a MAC. I've tried putting my files in there in another file aswell but nothing displays! I get this error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>   Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required `'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XXXXXXX/index.php'` (`include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/App‌​lications/XAMPP/xamp‌​pfiles/lib/php/pear'‌`​) in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas? Very new to PHP and Xampp!

Comment: What is C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php ?

Answer (score 1):

What system are you using, Win, Mac or Linux? On Mac when I try `http://localhost/` it redirects to `http://localhost/xampp/` and then there's the default welcome page.

Also, if you put you page(s) in a folder (`abc_folder/index.php` for example) under htdocs, you'll have to call it `http://localhost/abc_folder/index.php`

Comment: Thank you, i'm using a MAC. I've tried putting my files in there in another file aswell but nothing displays! I get this error: 
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XXXXXXX/index.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: ... did you make sure file permissions are set correctly? Did you try a simple 'Hello World' example first?

Answer (score 1):

You may have error reporting turned off in your `php.ini` file, and it could be something like a database error causing your pages to blank.

I would suggest putting this code into `test.php` and navigating to it.

```
<?PHP
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting up vhosts with Apache so you don't have to copy your files anywhere.

Here is a link to a [tutorial for setting up vhosts with xampp](http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is php start tag. Write it correctly and work.
Not `<?` but  `<?php` at all tags on the page.